# Is there a string function that can separate words joined with slash?

Tags: string, slash

For example if I have string "October/November", is there a function that can separate these two words into two strings "October" and "November"?

Comment: The answer will depend on the language you want to use  so please tag accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Python:

## Using f-strings

/ = ""
months = f"October{/}November"

print(months)

## If you want to make the output show November below October, you can just make / = "\n" or anything else depending on what you want

Comment: this code does is not valid neither in 2 nor 3 versions of Python. Also, it is not generic as, for instance, does not solve "September/October". Finally, even if it was syntactically correct, it does not seem to yield two strings...

Answer (score 0):

You may use https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp:

```
list_of_strings = "October/November".split("/")
```